# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. errro while setting user profile property

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, user-profile-property

I want to set the user profile property from code behind. The property is of type taxonomy(single value).

Following is a code which is I am executing:

```
SPList events = web.Lists["Calendar"];
//  Term term = null;
//  Term term1 = null;
SPListItem item = events.GetItemById(3);
if (item != null)
{
    TaxonomyFieldValueCollection valueColl = item["oiplbDepartment"] as TaxonomyFieldValueCollection;
    TaxonomyFieldValue value = valueColl[0];
    TaxonomyField field = item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("oiplbDepartment") as TaxonomyField;
    if (value != null)

    {
        TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
        TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[0];
        TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(field.TermSetId);
        //term = termSet.GetTerm(new Guid(value.TermGuid));
        //term1 = termSet.GetTerm(new Guid(valueColl[1].TermGuid));
        SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(@"xyz");
        if (user != null)
        {
            SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);                                
            UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
            UserProfile up = upm.GetUserProfile(@user.LoginName);
            up["oiplbNativeDepartment"].Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < valueColl.Count; i++)
            {
                Guid guid = new Guid(valueColl[i].TermGuid);
                Term t = termSet.GetTerm(guid);
                up["oiplbNativeDepartment"].AddTaxonomyTerm(t);
            }
            up.Commit();

        }


    }
}
```

I debugged the program and the error which is mentioned above comes at line `up["oiplbNativeDepartment"].AddTaxonomyTerm(t);` I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472885/sharepoint-2010-how-do-i-modify-a-taxonomic-property) post to set the user profile property.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, firstly, make sure that the property exists and isUserEditable as per below:

```
Guid guid = new Guid(valueColl[i].TermGuid);
Term t = termSet.GetTerm(guid);
var prop = up.Properties.GetPropertyByName("oiplbNativeDepartment");
if (prop != null && prop.IsUserEditable)
{
    up[prop.Name].Value = value;
}
```

Comment: I want to set the value to the user profile property not to the list. :-)

Comment: Apologies.. Check that?

Comment: Check condition fails at the statement `if(prop != null && prop.IsUserEditable)` but when I explicitly assign value like `up["oiplbNativeDepartment"].value = "Department 1"` then it assigns successfully.. What should I do to assign the term instead of string value?

Comment: Try to rather assign a TermValue than a string. A TermValue contains a Guid and Label for the term. But you're saying the Check condition fails.. What happens when you debug.. Is the prop null? THat means the property doesn't exist.

Comment: When I debug the code it does not go to the if condition's statements. And if the property is not exist, then how would I able to store the `.value` as string? like `up["oiplbNativeDepartment"].value = "Department 1"`

Comment: That means that your second condition is evaluating to false: prop.IsUserEditable. Are you running your code with Elevated Priviledges?

Comment: Sir, I am running this code in console application with system account.

Comment: One more thing I need to mention you is that I wrote following lines in code: ` UserProfileValueCollection coll = up["oiplbNativeDepartment"];coll.AddTaxonomyTerm(t);` that line also threw an exception. Can there be any issue with Term object?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this sir?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `for` loop given below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < valueColl.Count; i++)
{
    Guid guid = new Guid(valueColl[i].TermGuid);
    Term t = termSet.GetTerm(guid);
    up["oiplbNativeDepartment"].AddTaxonomyTerm(t);
}
```

Can you try the following:

Try `up["oiplbNativeDepartment"].Value = value;`

Comment: It gives compile time error that indicates: Property or indexer "Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfile.this[string]" cannot be assigned to read only property.

Comment: Please check update

Comment: Tried that way that throws an error: `'up["oiplbNativeDepartment"].Value' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'`

Comment: And one more thing I want to mention you sir, is that I have done this thing in "Multi Value" string taxonomy user profile property and this works perfectly. The problem persists for single value string user profile property only.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, if its single value why are you trying looping and adding all the Terms? It will accept an object of `TaxonomyFieldValue` as value, check the update

Comment: Thanks for responding sir, I tried that way also and throws the same exception. :-(

Comment: Did you get any solution for this sir?

Comment: Nop nothing in my mind yet..

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
userprofile["propertyname"].Add(" ");

userprofile["propertyname"].AddTaxonomyTerm(taxonomyterm);

userprofile.Commit();
```